# How copy the character with the specific size in another image at the same position as it was in the original image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I develop an application to recognize a text in an image. The image contains a lot of noise. That's why when i process to detect the edge in the image i consider only the edge that have a specific size. I will explain more.

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o0hqjvqc7t55cj/0.png) is my original image. I apply an edge detection after that i extract for example the first character "C"

```
    Mat img(aux,Rect(x,y,width,height));
```

Now i create a white image with the same size as the original.

```
    Mat image=cvCreateMat(original.rows,original.cols,original.type());
    image.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));
```

now i want to copy the "C" character in Mat image at the same position as it was in the original image. I do that but it gives me a wrong result.

```
    int j=10,x=40;
    cout<<img.rows<<" "<<img.cols;

    for (int k=0;k<img.cols;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++){
        image.at<uchar>(x,j)=img.at<uchar>(i,k );
        j++;
    }
    j=j+aux.rows-40;
    x++;
}
```

Any help please

Comment: `img` is your original image and `image` is your empty image? Where is the character "C"? Is it at `x=40, y=10` and what size (width/height) does it have?

Comment: img is the image which contains the "C" character i extract it from the original image. The character "C" is in X=40,y=10

Comment: what size does the character "C" have, in pixels: width and height? and what pixel type do `img` and `image/original` have? Or does `img` contain ONYL the character "C" and nothing else?` please upload `img` too...

Comment: I also note the height and width as img.cols and img.rows. img, image and original are black white image.

Comment: black and white with `8UC1` type or black and white with `8UC3` (e.g. loaded with imread)?

Comment: the "C" character is there https://www.dropbox.com/s/emxx6ssnjkyf6yf/xx.png

Comment: yes loaded with imread

Comment: then you most probably may not use `uchar` but `Vec3b` if you didnt `cv::cvtColor` to grayscale first (or use the LOAD GRAYSCALE flag).

Comment: added two answers, one with .copyTo and one with pixel-wise copying for both types: `uchar` and `Vec3b`

Comment: having another look at your code, except the maybe-type-problem I only see one thing that might be wrong: `j=j+aux.rows-40;` could be changed to `j=j-img.rows;` which should reset j to 10 after every inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the `.copyTo` way to do it:

```
    int main()
    {
        //here: read original image as 8UC3 (which is an RBG image)
        cv::Mat original = cv::imread("characterC_original.png");

        // here: read original image as 8UC1 (which is grayscale)
        //cv::Mat original = cv::imread("characterC_original.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        // this is the image with the character only. In 8UC3 type too
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread("characterC.png");
        //cv::Mat img = cv::imread("characterC.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        // this is where the character was placed in original. If you have this information already somehwere else, you can use that directly. So you don't even need to have that `img` if you know offset, width and height
        int offsetX = 40;
        int offsetY = 10;
        int width = img.cols;
        int height = img.rows;

        cv::Rect characterLocation = cv::Rect(offsetX, offsetY, width, height);

        cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(original.rows, original.cols, original.type());
        image.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));

        original(characterLocation).copyTo(image(characterLocation));

        cv::imshow("original", original);
        cv::imshow("char copied", image);
        cv::imwrite("characterC_result.png", image);
        cv::waitKey(-1);
    }
```

giving me this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

given the case that `img` is already the subimage holding the character and you know where this subimage was placed in the original image, and given that both images are `8UC1`type:

```
int offsetY=10;
int offsetX=40;

for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
    for (int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
    {

        image.at<uchar>(j+offsetY,i+offsetX)=img.at<uchar>(j,i);
    }
```

If both images are not `8UC1` type but `8UC3` type, replace both `<uchar>` with `<Vec3b>. If one of them is`8UC1`and the other is`8UC3` you will have to convert first or convert manually.

If `img` is unchanged subimage from `original` you could easily use and copy the subimage directly without creation of `img`, which will be faster and you won't have to care about the type.

here are both examples:

grayscale images:

```
    int main()
    {
        // here: read original image as 8UC1 (which is grayscale)
        cv::Mat original = cv::imread("characterC_original.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        // this is the image with the character only. In 8UC1 type too
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread("characterC.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        // this is where the character was placed in original. If you have this informationalready somehwere else, you can use that directly.
        int offsetX = 40;
        int offsetY = 10;
        int width = img.cols;
        int height = img.rows;


        cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(original.rows, original.cols, original.type());
        image.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));


        for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
            for (int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
            {
// here you use uchar since it's 8UC1
                image.at<uchar>(j+offsetY,i+offsetX)=img.at<uchar>(j,i);
            }

        cv::imshow("original", original);
        cv::imshow("char copied", image);
        cv::imwrite("characterC_result_8UC1.png", image);
        cv::waitKey(-1);
    }
```

and this is for black and white images embedded in RGB images:

```
    int main()
    {
        //here: read original image as 8UC3 (which is an RBG image)
        cv::Mat original = cv::imread("characterC_original.png");

        // this is the image with the character only. In 8UC3 type too
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread("characterC.png");

        // this is where the character was placed in original. If you have this informationalready somehwere else, you can use that directly.
        int offsetX = 40;
        int offsetY = 10;
        int width = img.cols;
        int height = img.rows;


        cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(original.rows, original.cols, original.type());
        image.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));


        for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
            for (int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
            {
// here you use Vec3b since you have RGB type
                image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j+offsetY,i+offsetX)=img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
            }

        cv::imshow("original", original);
        cv::imshow("char copied", image);
        cv::imwrite("characterC_result_8UC3.png", image);
        cv::waitKey(-1);
    }
```

I tested both and they work.

Comment: this is image https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5e4wikqjtnguok/image.png and i want obtain this result https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpt5t5rv4qvmroy/result.png